# How to tell if TypeWriter Parameter Type is an Interface

Tags: c#, typewriter

How would you be able to tell if the parameter retrieved from a method is itself an interface?

These attempts below does not seem to work:

```
 method.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type.Interfaces)
 method.Parameters.Select(p => p.Type.NestedInterfaces)
 method.Type.Interfaces
```

Why isn't there an .IsInterface on the TypeWriter Type? You can call .IsEnum but no .IsInterface

Comment: Sure there is **Type.IsInterface** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isinterface?view=net-5.0

`method.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type.IsInterface)`